# How to replace forward slashes with backslashes in a string in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: regex, emacs, string, lisp

I would like to replace forward slashes with backslashes in emacs lisp.
If I use this :

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "\/" "\\" path))
```

I get an error.

```
(error "Invalid use of `\\' in replacement text")
```

So how to represent the backslash in the second regexp?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are seeing in `"C:\\foo\\bar"` is the textual representation of the string `"C:\foo\bar"`, with escaped backslashes for further processing.

For example, if you make a string of length 1 with the backslash character:

```
(make-string 1 ?\\)
```

you get the following response (e.g. in the minibuffer, when you evaluate the above with C-x C-e):

```
"\\"
```

Another way to get what you want is to switch the "literal" flag on:

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "/" "\\" path t t)
```

By the way, you don't need to escape the slash.

Answer (score 6):

Does it need to be double-escaped?

i.e.

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "\/" "\\\\" path)
```

Comment: yep :-) but that's a syntax error (the last quote is escaped than)

Comment: Another thought - this doesn't need to be a regex replace, since it's a straight substitution - does emacs/lisp offer a non-regex replace?

Comment: Double-escaped, ie. 4 consecutive backslashes *do* work.
The reason you see 2 consecutive backslashes in the result is that they are escaped in the string. If you try to output the string again, it will look correct.

Comment: You can also write it like this for better readability:

(replace-regexp-in-string "/" (regexp-quote "\\") path)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the regexp-quote function, like so:

`(replace-regexp-in-string "/" (regexp-quote "\\") "this/is//a/test")`

regexp-quote's documentation reads

> (regexp-quote string)
>   Return a regexp string which matches exactly string and nothing else.

Comment: Not to rain on your parade but this answer was given up in the comments of the 2nd answer.

Comment: Oops, missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use emacs but I guess it supports some form of specifying unicode via \x

e.g. maybe this works

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "\x005c" "\x005f" path))
```

or

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "\u005c" "\u005f" path))
```

Comment: um ok then switch to \u005c and \u005f? not?